A "permission denied" error occurs when installing a new Python version with uv
I typed:
uv python install 3.12 -v

And here is the error result:
DEBUG uv 0.4.21
DEBUG Acquired lock for `/profils/username/.local/share/uv/python`
Searching for Python versions matching: Python 3.12
DEBUG Using request timeout of 30s
DEBUG Downloading https://github.com/indygreg/python-build-standalone/releases/download/20241008/cpython-3.12.7%2B20241008-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-install_only_stripped.tar.gz to temporary location: /profils/username/.local/share/uv/python/.cache/.tmpuAUEAN
DEBUG Extracting cpython-3.12.7%2B20241008-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-install_only_stripped.tar.gz
error: Failed to install cpython-3.12.7-linux-x86_64-gnu
  Caused by: Failed to extract archive: cpython-3.12.7%2B20241008-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-install_only_stripped.tar.gz
  Caused by: failed to unpack `/profils/username/.local/share/uv/python/.cache/.tmpuAUEAN/python/share/terminfo/e/eterm`
  Caused by: failed to unpack `python/share/terminfo/e/eterm` into `/profils/username/.local/share/uv/python/.cache/.tmpuAUEAN/python/share/terminfo/e/eterm`
  Caused by: Permission denied (os error 13)
DEBUG Released lock at `/profils/username/.local/share/uv/python/.lock`

I gave the full permission to all folders in /profils/username/.local/share/uv, but the error stayed the same.
